# Changing the OS X Mountain Lion LoginWindow

Tags: macos, customization, loginview

I want to create a custom Login Window for OS X Mountain Lion. In older versions of OS X there was a LoginWindowUI.nib which you could change with the Interface Builder but the file is not present on Mountain Lion.

My goal is to do something like the LightDM Webkit Greeter project which enables a user to create a custom login window with HTML, CSS and JS for OS X.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.